# Sending binary data in javascript over HTTP

Tags: javascript, ajax, binary, hex

I'm trying to send a HTTP POST to a device on my network.  I want to send four specific bytes of data to the device unfortunately I only seem to be able to send strings to the device.  Is there anyway to send raw binary using javascript?

Here's the script I'm using to do the POST, it currently doesn't run unless I put a string in the data field.  Any ideas?

```
(function ($) {
   $.ajax({
      url: '<IP of Address>',
      type: 'POST',
      contentType: 'application/octet-stream',

      //data:'253,0,128,1',
      data:0xFD008001,

      crossDomain: true
   });
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 54, accepted):

By default, jQuery serializes the data (passed in `data` property) - and it means `0xFD008001` *number* gets passed to the server as '4244668417' *string* (10 bytes, not 4), that's why the server treats it not as expected.

It's necessary to prevent such behaviour by setting `$.ajax` property `processData` to `false`:

> By default, data passed in to the data option as an object
>   (technically, anything other than a string) will be processed and
>   transformed into a query string, fitting to the default content-type
>   "application/x-www-form-urlencoded". If you want to send a
>   DOMDocument, or other non-processed data, set this option to false.

... but that's only part of the whole story: `XMLHttpRequest.send` implementation has its own [restrictions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#Browser_Compatibility). That's why your best bet, I suppose, is to make your own serializer using [**TypedArrays**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays):

```
// Since we deal with Firefox and Chrome only 
var bytesToSend = [253, 0, 128, 1],
    bytesArray = new Uint8Array(bytesToSend);

$.ajax({
   url: '%your_service_url%',
   type: 'POST',
   contentType: 'application/octet-stream',  
   data: bytesArray,
   processData: false
});
```

Or without using jQuery at all:

```
var bytesToSend = [253, 0, 128, 1],
    bytesArray = new Uint8Array(bytesToSend);

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', '%your_service_url%');
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/octet-stream');
xhr.send(bytesArray);
```

Comment: I get `ArrayBuffer is deprecated in XMLHttpRequest.send(). Use ArrayBufferView instead.` but then get a `ReferenceError: ArrayBufferView is not defined`

Comment: Yes, I've rewritten this to not use `ArrayBuffer`; typedArray are actually supported both by Chrome and Firefox as `xhr.send` param.

Comment: Thanks for this!  I'm quite new to javascript so I was thinking there was something simple I was missing. Your explanation definitely went above and beyond.  Thanks!

Comment: There's no need for your loops above. The typed array constructors accept array-like objects and do the loop for you. So just `var bytesArray = new Uint8Array(bytesToSend);` is all you need. [Details here](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-typedarray-object), but I didn't want to edit that in unilaterally.

Comment: I see your point, but what about browser support? I've assumed using `new TypedArray(plainArray)` construct is only possible in the browsers that support `TypedArray.from(plainArray)`, and judging from [this docpage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray/from), IE and Safari don't allow that.

Comment: Ah, just noticed the original recipe (using `ArrayBufferView` as `xhr.send` param) was only for Firefox and Chrome... And, surprise, surprise, it looks like it's the same thing in Aug'16, IE and Safari still don't support that.

Answer (score 8):

You can send binary data via ajax with xhr2, you can send the data as a typed array or a [blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob).

```
(function ($) {
   var data = new Uint32Array(1);
   data[0] = 0xFD008001; 
   $.ajax({
      url: '<IP of Address>',
      type: 'POST',
      contentType: false,
      processData: false,
      //data:'253,0,128,1',
      data:data,

      crossDomain: true
   });
})(jQuery);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Uint32Array

Comment: +1, but this actually sends the bytes in the reverse order. )

Comment: Well I wasn't thinking of it as a sequence of bytes but as a u32 int.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert your data with type of ArrayBuffer to a ArrayBufferView like this:

```js
var fileContent = new DataView(<ArrayBuffer_data>);
```

With this you wont get a warning in the console when sending fileContent.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `atob()` and `btoa()`:

```
var data = new Uint32Array(1);
data[0] = 0xFD008001;
atob(data)
```

This converts your binary data into a base64 string that can be sent as text.