# Sending UInt8Array through $.ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to send compressed data to a server. To do this I'm attempting to pass it into jQuery's ajax function as a UInt8Array. I've based this on a [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19959072/sending-binary-data-in-javascript-over-http).

But it's not worked. When I look at the content through Wireshark, I see it's tried to do a .toString() on it, getting "[object Uint8Array]". There's very little other info on this around.

```
var dataCompressed = LZW.compressToByteArray(data);
  $.ajax({
     data: dataCompressed,
     processData: false,
     contentType: "application/octet-stream",
     url: window.localStorage.getItem('servername') + '/Form/SaveData2?formId=' + results.rows.item(x).id,
     headers: { 'Authorization': 'Basic ' + credentials },
     type: "POST",
     async: true,
     success: function (data) {
     }
  });
```

Comment: Try putting it through `new Blob`

Comment: Could try encoding in base64

Comment: `$.ajax` is a shortcut for `XMLHttpRequest`, which in reality only supports sending strings. jQuery converts arrays and objects to strings for you, so it has to support converting the data otherwise it won't work, and it probably doesn't support UInt8Array, which means you have to iterate and convert it to a string yourself.

Comment: @adeneo you can send _Blob_ and _File_ with _XMLHttpRequest_

Comment: @user1094553- tried it and it just gives me that string in base64. Which I probably should have realised.

Comment: @PaulS.- I'm unfamiliar with Blobs, and I get an "Illegal constructor" error on attempting it. I assume I'm doing something wrong, but I'm finishing for the day now. It would be helpful if you could amend my code in an answer- then I can mark it as correct if it works.

Comment: @user2564511 which browser is giving you an _Illegal constructor_ warning?

Comment: @PaulS. - Indeed, modern browsers support FormData, which is somewhat an exception to the rule that XMLHttpRequest only accepts strings.

Answer (score 1):

You need to serialize the ArrayBuffer before jQuery tries to convert it for you. Some examples of how to do this can be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9673053/133416).

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a *Blob*,

```
var blob = new Blob([dataCompressed], {type: "application/octet-stream"});
// ...
    data: blob,
```

If *jQuery* is still handling this wrong, you could put this into a *FormData*

```
var fd = new FormData();
fd.append('post_field_name', blob, 'optional_file_name');
// ...
    data: fd,
```

Doing it one of these ways is effectively "POSTing a *File* with *AJAX*"

---

I don't use *jQuery* so whilst I assume one of the above works I've not tested it. You may find that *jQuery* doesn't support posting data like this and have to move to a *vanilla* solution

Comment: I've put that in and I'm still getting "Illegal constructor" where it's creating the Blob. That's using a mobile version of Chrome. Looking at MDN, mobile support is spotty, but the whole point of this is to do it for mobile, so I'll need to find an alternative.

I'll try for a native solution- jQuery has functions to override how it performs many interactions so I'll look into that.