# post binary code not working from Jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I made this code to make image upload function but the variable is not getting posted by ajax please help me !!
Jquery()

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#btn").click(function() {
    $.get("i.png", function(response) {


 var img = response;
}); 

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'lol.php',
    data: {r: img},
    success: function(data){
        $("#ol").html(data)

    }

});
return false;
});
});

</script>
```

PHP Code

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","image");
$r = $_POST['r'];
echo $r;

?>
```

Comment: put ajax call inside .get return

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sending binary data in javascript over HTTP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19959072/sending-binary-data-in-javascript-over-http)

Comment: thanks artm it worked .............

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to make an image upload (and not exactly match "binary upload")

I suggest you to use the proper functional and native input type file.

**In a html form, put an :**

```
<input type="file" id="upload">
<img src="blank.png" title="upload-preview">
```

**and in you javascript:**

this will load the preview thumbnail selected

```
fileInput.addEventListener("change", function(event)
{
    var file = $("#upload")[0].files[0];
    $(".upload-preview").attr('src', window.URL.createObjectURL(file));
});
```

and when you click the button, that will send the image

with a **"multipart/form-data"** Content-Type

```
$("#btn").on("click", function()
{
    var inputs = new FormData();
    inputs.append("upload", $("#upload")[0].files[0]);

    $.ajax
    ({
        url:"your.php",
        type:"POST",
        data: inputs,
        cache: false, // don't cache the image
        processData: false, // Don't process the files
        contentType: false,
        success: function(response)
        {
            // next instructions
        }
    });
});
```