# Making Ajax REST calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, rest, curl

How I can convert the following `cURL` into an `ajax` REST call?

```
    curl -u "{username}":"{password}" \
-H "content-type: audio/wav" \
--data-binary @"/path/to/file.wav" \
"https://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api/v1/recognize"
```

I added few of it to below ajax call, I do no know how to add the rest of it, specially the part mentioned in `-H` and `--data-binary @`

```
function restCall()
            {
                $.ajax
                ({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "https://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api/v1/recognize",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    username: "xxxx",
                    password: "xxxx",

                    success: function (data){
                        alert(JSON.stringify(data)); 
                    }
                });
            }
```

Comment: This might help for the headers http://stackoverflow.com/a/3258685/4759033

Comment: and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19959072/sending-binary-data-in-javascript-over-http