# How to form raw binary payload request("Content-Type:application/octet-stream") from javascript

Tags: javascript, byte, arrays

I am trying to form a `Content-Type: application/octet-stream` PUT request from JavaScript where the body will be raw binary (`byte[]`). I have a Base-64 encoded string of the binary data which is a random file content. I need to decode this back to a byte array and put it into the request body.

The `curl` command I could use to do this is:

```
curl -v -X PUT --header "Content-Type:application/octet-stream" --data-binary "@myfile" http://localhost:8080/my-services/myapi
```

How can I do that in JavaScript?

Comment: You want to do this in a *browser*, right? Not NodeJS or similar?

Comment: And if so, are you using jQuery? Because if you are: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19959072/sending-binary-data-in-javascript-over-http (pretty much answers this even if you aren't using jQuery, if you're doing this on a browser).

Comment: I've added a non-jQuery version of the answer there, so this is a duplicate if you're doing it from a browser.

Comment: Stack Overflow is **really active**. Please don't post a question and disappear. Stick around for a while so you can answer questions from people trying to help you.