# Upload Excel to Slack using files.upload API - file uploads, but is corrupted

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, slack-api

I'm using Slack's *files.upload* API to upload an Excel doc retrieved from an AJAX response.  I'm using jQuery's AJAX for the upload and the file is uploading correctly except that it's corrupted.  When I open the file downloaded from Slack, it contains many "?"s and other characters indicative of bad encoding.  Downloading the file and then uploading using Slack's [tester tool](https://api.slack.com/methods/files.upload/test), works correctly and does not result in corruption.

The most relevant portion is the `ajaxConfig`; this is the object passed to jQuery's `ajax()` method.

```js
self.getClient().runReport({
    query: queryString,
    success: function(response){
        var formEnc = new FormData();
        formEnc.append('file', new Blob([response], {type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'}), 'filename.xls');
        self.getClient().slackFile({
            filename: 'MyReport.xls',
            channel: '%23my-channel',
            ajaxConfig: {
                method: 'post',
                data: formEnc,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                mimeType: 'multipart/form-data',
                success: function(response){
                    resolve(response);
                },
                error: function(response){
                    reject(response);
                }
            }
        });
    },
    error: function(msg){
        reject(msg);
    }
});
```

I've tried different types for the `Blob` and the `mimeType` without success, though I don't think this is the problem because the POST request that I'm sending looks the same as the one generated by Slack's tester tool (which uploaded the file without corruption).  I suspect that the problem must be in how I'm encoding the response I get from `runReport` (remember that I can download that file manually just fine).

---

**Update**
I used [FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js) to download the response and the file is corrupted in the same way, so it's not related to the POST to Slack.  It must be the encoding.

Comment: I am not a Javascript expert, but that looks like an data encoding problem. This answer might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19959072/sending-binary-data-in-javascript-over-http

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It ended up being an an encoding problem caused by jquery.  The upload works fine when using straight xhr.

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open(method, url);
req.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
req.onload = function(){
    success(req.response);
};
req.send();
```