# Cognitive Emotions Video - how to send video to body

Tags: video-processing, azure-cognitive-services, jquery-ajaxq

I need to send video from disk to Cognitive Services Emotion. I have almost done, but I was not capable to figure out how to format body properly and I can´t use '{url: http://...}' because I can´t expose the videos I want to submit. My code:

```
$.ajax({
            "headers":{
                "Content-Type":"application/octet-stream",
                "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key":"SECRET"
            },        
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            "data": JSON.stringify({video: data}),
            success: (x,stat,res) => {
            },
            error: (res) => {
            }
        });
```

As you can see I´ve tried to use 'octet-stream' to send the video. And that is one of many ways I did it. I don´t know if I need to send a JSON(similar when you send url) or do something else. I couldn´t find anything about it on official documentation. Help??

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at [Sending binary data in javascript over HTTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19959072/sending-binary-data-in-javascript-over-http).

```
$.ajax({
            "headers":{
                "Content-Type":"application/octet-stream",
                "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key":"SECRET"
            },        
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: data,
            success: (x,stat,res) => {
            },
            error: (res) => {
            }
        });
```

You want the body payload to be the raw (unencoded) binary data for Cognitive Services.  The accepted formats are listed [here](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5639d931ca73072154c1ce89/operations/56f8d40e1984551ec0a0984e).

One other important thing to remember is that jQuery calls the error handler for HTTP 202 [responses](https://http.cat/202), which is what you get from this API.  So your error handler needs to handle that case, or, more to the point, your success handler won't ever be called.

Comment: Yes, I read the documentation, thank you very much!  There is no useful information about  how to format data for videos nor examples. And the emulator doesn´t helps to find out how am I supposed to format the data. The article about how to send binary data in Javascript doesn´t helps too because problems are a little bit different. Trying to explain better, I´m using FileReader to read video from the disk using readAsDataURL(file) as "encoder". I did that because works for images. But is not that for upload videos and documentation about it is not clear for me.

Comment: If you have a DataURI, you need to convert this to a binary buffer.  [Post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/807ee18d-45e5-410b-a339-c8dcb3bfa25b/testing-project-oxford-ocr-how-to-use-a-local-file-in-base64-for-example?forum=mlapi) is for a different Microsoft API but the same will work for you.