# Save javascript BLOB to database through java

Tags: javascript, java, blob, inputstream

I am currently doing a sound recording using JavaScript and I have a BLOB URL data as an output. 
Is there anywhere that I can send this data and save it in Database through java using Input Stream?

Sample of BLOB URL DATA which was generated after recoding the audio: 
blob:http://127.0.0.1:8888/363f3a17-81d0-4f4d-915c-8d01d288b8bc

Comment: Maybe two parts to this question a) send binary data from JS -> Servlet b) Save Bob to DB

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/19960111/2310289

Comment: I have sent the BLOB to servlet, and set it into a File but it was shown error.

Comment: we are not mind-readers - tell us what the problem is, and [Please add a minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)