# How to send byte array from javascript to java servlet through ajax

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, jakarta-ee

I have a byte array in front-end generated by javascript that I want to send to java servlet through ajax. How can I do that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19959072/sending-binary-data-in-javascript-over-http

Answer (score 0):

See [this q&a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19959072/sending-binary-data-in-javascript-over-http) which discusses a jquery solution but also offers a vanilla js solution

```
var bytesToSend = [253, 0, 128, 1],
bytesArray = new Uint8Array(bytesToSend);
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', '%your_service_url%');
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/octet-stream');
xhr.send(bytesArray);
```