# Why is the uploaded data from FileReader more than the file's length?

Tags: javascript, binary, filereader

I want to use a `FileReader` to `POST` an Excel file to my interface. It all works (as in there are no errors), except that the data sent seems to be mangled somewhere. When checking the wire, I can see the `POST` has a `Content-Length` of 11910 bytes, while my uploaded file is only 8852 bytes large.

This is the Javascript code:

```
function readfile() {
    // #excelFile is a simple <input type="file">
    var file = $("#excelFile")[0].files[0];

    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.addEventListener("load", (event) => {
        restPutPost("post", "rest/mapping", reader.result, 
        function(data) {
            console.log(`File ${file.name} uploaded.`);
        }, 
        function(xhr, status, error) {
            console.log(`Upload failed: ${error}`);
        }, 
        "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
    });

    reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
}
```

and the `restPutPost` is a convenience function I wrote:

```
function restPutPost(method, url, body, callback = null, errorcallback = null, contenttype = "application/json") {
    actualbody = body;
    if (contenttype == "application/json") {
        actualbody = body != null?JSON.stringify(body): null;
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: method,
        url: url,
        headers: {
            Accept: "application/json"
        },
        data: actualbody,
        contentType: contenttype,
        success: function (data) {
            if (callback != null) {
                callback(data);
            }
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            if (errorcallback != null) {
                errorcallback(xhr, xhr.status, error);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: What does `console.log(reader.result.length)` show?

Comment: @Barmar I just checked. It is all 8852 bytes. Even `actualbody` has the correct length.

Comment: What is the `Content-Transfer-Encoding` header? I suspect it's being converted to base 64.

Comment: @Barmar yes. And the `Content-Length` in the request header (Chrome 109 on Windows) says 11920 as well.

Comment: `Content-Transfer-Encoding` is not set.

Comment: When I check the payload, it doesn't look like Base64

Comment: Can you compare the source and destination files to see what was added?

Comment: It looks like some UTF-8 encoding is going on or so. I can see an `0xEE9D` bytes in the original being translated to `0xC3AEC2`

Comment: From the jQuery website: " Note: The W3C XMLHttpRequest specification dictates that the charset is always UTF-8; specifying another charset will not force the browser to change the encoding."

Comment: I had a feeling that's what's going on. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19959072/sending-binary-data-in-javascript-over-http

Comment: @Barmar, thanks. I'll update my code to use Base64, then I'll always be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into a few issues with sending binary data. First, the jQuery XHR does not guarantee the data is untouched. Second, JSON does not support binary data.

So, to fix the issue, I decided to transform the binary data into Base64, and put that into a JSON object:

```
var obj = {}
obj["exceldata"] = btoa(reader.result);

restPutPost("post", "rest/mapping", obj);
```

This way, my entire interface stays JSON and I can still send binary data.